# Does bounty count against my ability to post questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

So I'm searching through my profile, trying to find ways to improve my reputation since I've been blocked, and I see this:

[image]

Do bounties affect reputation? Or in other words, *and I'm not saying it's the reason*, but is there a higher possibility that I could post questions today if I didn't have those -40 under my rep?

Comment: They can, if they bring attention to a question that is then perceived as being low quality. but the rep lost from offering the bounty itself shouldn't have any effect.

Answer (score 19):

> Do bounties affect reputation?

Well, yeah.  You're looking right at your reputation history and seeing the bounty listed and its affect on your reputation.

> is there a higher possibility that I could post questions today if I didn't have those -40 under my rep?

Its effect on the *post ban* is quite different.  The post ban doesn't look at your reputation. The post ban looks at what positive and negative contributions you've made and makes a determination as to whether or not it thinks you're a user that is capable of providing acceptable contributions or not.

The specifics of the post ban algorithm are not made public, but it's pretty safe to say that "posted a bounty" is not a sign that a user isn't capable of providing a quality question (it's not a sign that they are more likely to post *good* quesitons either), so I wouldn't expect it to be a factor in the post ban (either positively or negatively).  But we can only guess, because again, it's not public.

Comment: I've seen a lot of users lately when the downvotes came in and close votes that they posted a bounty on their questions of 50 points preventing any new close votes. This answer remindend me of that heh.

Comment: @Tschallacka You can flag the post for moderator attention in the hopes that they'll address the situation.  Usually it takes them more than a week to notice the flag, and so nothing happens, but sometimes you get lucky and they get to the flag with enough time to do something about it.

Answer (score 8):

No.  Question bans factor, predominantly among other things, how well your questions are received.  Bounties do not factor much in this given that they are not indications of question quality (i.e. you cannot award a bounty to a *question*).

You would be best served combing through your existing questions and seeing if you could make those better received.  Remember:  zero-scored questions are questions which aren't well-received, too.

Comment: "Question bans only factor how well your questions are received" We know that things beyond just that is factored in.  That's the most important factor, sure, but not the *only* factor.

Comment: @Servy:  Thanks; reworded.

Comment: "Zero-scored questions are questions which aren't well-received, too." I've always felt this was unfortunate, especially on low-traffic sites, where the questions gets upvoted answers. But it is what it is.

Comment: @ouflak a question with upvoted answers might be considered by the system good, as the question generated good posts from others.